# Trig/Complex Numbers Problem in Riley Math Methods

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble with a solution to a problem in Riley's Math Methods book. I've presented the problem and solution in the two pictures below (question b) only), but essentially I am wondering why, in the case where the two are out of phase by $\pi$, we can then easily conclude that $c_ib_r = c_rb_i$. My thinking is as follows.
If the two are $\pi$ radians out of phase, then the angles (phases) of B and C are related by
$$ \pm\pi = tan^{-1}(b_i/b_r) - tan^{-1}(c_i/c_r) $$
but from there I cannot see how we can conclude that $b_i/b_r = c_i/c_r$ and thus that $c_ib_r = c_rb_i$. In the case where their phase difference is $0$ this is easily seen.

[Question b) only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yJvk.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGBp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b$ and $c$ are $\pi$ out of phase, then $\Im bc^*=-b_rc_i+b_ic_r=0$. I guess the easiest way to see that is that if $b=r_be^{i\theta}$ then $c=r_ce^{i(\theta+\pi)}=-r_ce^{i\theta}$ so $bc^*=-r_br_c\in\mathbb{R}$. But what I would have done is to say that
$$z=a+bt+ct^2=a-\frac{b^2}{4c^2}c+\left(t+\frac b{2c}\right)^2c$$
That way you can see that it's a ray starting at
$$z=a-\frac{b^2}{4c^2}c$$
And going in the direction of $c$. Also from the ray formulation you can get
$$x=a_r-\frac{b^2}{4c^2}c_r+\left(t-\frac b{2c}\right)^2c_r$$
$$y=a_i-\frac{b^2}{4c^2}c_i+\left(t-\frac b{2c}\right)^2c_i$$
Multiplying the first equation above by $c_i$ and the second by $c_r$ and subtracting you get
$$c_ix-c_ry=a_rc_i-a_ic_r$$
In the first question make sure you exclude $z=c-\rho$!

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac {b_i}{c_i} = V$ and $\dfrac {b_r}{c_r} = W$. If $\tan W = \tan V$ we get the solution (after taking the arctangent of both sides) $$V = \pi k + W$$

If we let $k=0$ $$V = W \rightarrow \dfrac {b_i}{c_i} =  \dfrac {b_r}{c_r}$$ and hence $${b_i}{c_r} = {b_r}{c_i} \implies {b_i}{c_r} - {b_r}{c_i} = 0$$ and thus $t$ vanishes (as $t \cdot 0 = 0$).